# How to place a video within an existing 3D scene (via .bpy/python script)?

Tags: scripting, video

I currently have a sphere spinning around a cube,
and the main camera spinning around the same cube on another axis of rotation

I would like to replace the cube with a 2D video clip.

Is this achievable?

Comment: Perhaps I don't fully understand the question, but could you not just import the video file using the Import Images as Planes option? Do you need to mask/show the video in a more specific way?

Comment: I wasn't familiar with 'Import Images as Planes', that's useful information, thanks.

Comment: I'll pore through the source code for that addon

Comment: It's useful because during import you can choose the type of material (emission best for your app), as well as a video source instead of a still image.

Comment: Go and add a screenshot of your setup, please.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure that you can extrapolate this to python, but this would be my approach:

If this is an animation, you can place a keyframe on the object's render icon.

eg. in the outliner hover the mouse over the icon and hit the <kbd>I</kbd> key.
For the cube, goto frame 1, with the camera icon on, add a keyframe.
For the image plane on the same frame, click the camera icon to turn it off, and add a keyframe.

THEN

goto the frame that you want to swap the visibility and inverse what is on and what is off, then add your respective keyframes again.

---

**Per the comment response i am going to expound on this clarification - Please Refer to the end of this answer for the steps that I propose to accomplish your efforts.**

My guess is that I did not understand your question properly.
Are you using the cube as a place holder for the 2D movie?

OR

Are you trying to transition an effect two morph between the visibility of a cube to a 2D Movie plane?

OR

Something else altogether?

**Appended since clarification**

1. Since I believe that you are using a cube as a placeholder reference to rotate your cameras around, mark the center of that cube by selecting it, then use the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> >> Cursor To Selected, unless you have moved the origin of the cube this should work. If you have moved the origin, it would be wise to go into edit mode, <kbd>A</kbd> to select all, then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> >> Cursor To Selected, then back to object mode.
2. Delete the cube.
3. identify your video size (eg. 1920x1080)
4. Add a plane to your scene of the same dimensional ratio (eg. 1.920x1.080)
5. Go into edit mode on the newly created plane and UV unwrap it by <kbd>A</kbd> to select all vertices >> <kbd>U</kbd> >> Unwrap >> <kbd>Tab</kbd> to go back to object mode.
6. Go into the materials panel and make sure that the object has one (Assuming Blender Render here, there is a different workflow for Cycles, which I will post if this is required), and add a material if needed (Hint: you may want to check Shadeless, otherwise you may be very dissatisfied that your plane reflects other things in your scene).
7. Go to the Textures tab and add a texture, for the type select "Image or Movie", then be sure that Auto Refresh is checked, then in the Image section, browse to your video file, then in the Mapping section set coordinates to UV.

This should do the trick.

Good Luck

Comment: Are you suggesting: load all the video frames as individual images in the same location and toggle the visibility of these based on frame number?

Comment: No I would add you image sequence in as a movie strip, and make your movie be your material for whatever piece of geometry you want to associate it to.

Comment: The question was poorly worded, apologies, the cube isn't really relevant. I meant 'I would like a mesh plane with a movie/image sequence on it', but I wasn't aware of the right nomenclature at the time I asked the question.

Comment: OK, then I will edit the answer to suit. Thanks for the response.